# How to prevent failed requests when performing WebDeploy?

Tags: .net, webdeploy, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebApi running on IIS setup via OWIN Startup class. After I deploy from Visual Studio several requests always fail. This windows only lasts for couple of senconds. Everything is fine after that.

I get exceptions like these:

```
System.ArgumentException: The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property 'InnerHandler' of 'CorsMessageHandler' is not null.
Parameter name: handlers
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, IEnumerable`1 handlers)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<EnsureInitialized>b__b()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

or:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Web.Http.HttpServer'.
   at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.set_InnerHandler(HttpMessageHandler value)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<EnsureInitialized>b__b()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I log these from HttpApplicationContext.Error event handler in a IHttpModule.Init. They don't reach WebApi's IExceptionLogger. These happen after my Startup has already run (appears in log before these exceptions).

I looking to minimize the number of failed requests when deploying.

Where do I start?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't tolerate any blips during deploy, you may want to consider a "Blue/Green Deploy" approach:

Have 2 separate Applications under your IIS Site - one for what's currently in production, and one for the staging/on-deck build that you push via WebDeploy.  Once the WebDeploy has succeeded, you can point your production IIS Application at this new folder.  The old folder is now a short-term backup that you can flip back to if anything blows up, and can later be re-purposed as the staging/on-deck for the next deploy.

Of course you can automate this more, but that's the basic idea.